# how to make decimal number to integer dynamically

Tags: python, numpy

I have data like below:

```
a = np.array([[61.22, 92.92, -53.0],
              [-0.272, 0.2828, -0.737],
              [12.43, -0.732, 0.82],
              [52.1, -62.12, 37.78],
              [0.1, 0.67, -0.22],
              [-0.09, -0.28, 0.22],
              [82.1, -11.12, 45.78],
              [-52.1, 0.12, -37.78]])
```

if index 1-3 in array contains numbers == 0 all i want to change it to 0.

the expectation result such below:

```
 a = np.array([[61.22, 92.92, -53.0],
              [0.,0., 0.],
              [12.43, -0.732, 0.82],
              [52.1, -62.12, 37.78],
              [0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0.],
              [82.1, -11.12, 45.78],
              [-52.1, 0.12, -37.78]])
```

I've try use simple code but its doesn't work:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i].all()==0:
    a[i] = np.round(a[i],0)
```

Comment: None of those values are actually 0.

Comment: @Woodford What do you mean? They've already shown it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively you want to check if numbers start with 0, i.e., if their absolute value is smaller than 1. In that case you could use:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if (np.abs(a[i]) < 1).all():
        a[i] = 0
```

Comment: but sometime the data will be negative such as (-78.922,82.22,82.92). so in this case we can't use abs() because its will change the negative value to positif

Comment: I'm not sure what your use-case is. But my suggestion does *not* change the data in `a`. It just uses absolute value for the if statement. You'll see that if you change numbers in `a` to negative, they won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
a = np.array([[61.22,92.92,53.0],
             [-0.272,0.2828,-0.737],
             [12.43,-0.732,0.82],
             [52.1,62.12,37.78],
             [0.1,0.67,-0.22],
             [-.09,-0.28,0.22],
             [82.1,11.12,45.78],
             [52.1,0.12,37.78]])

a[np.all(np.abs(a) < 1, axis=1), :] = 0

# a is now:
#
# array([[61.22 , 92.92 , 53.   ],
#       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
#       [12.43 , -0.732,  0.82 ],
#       [52.1  , 62.12 , 37.78 ],
#       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
#       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ],
#       [82.1  , 11.12 , 45.78 ],
#       [52.1  ,  0.12 , 37.78 ]])
```

Your issue was that you were checking `if a[i].all()==0:` but what you want is absolute value of all numbers in row smaller than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[61.22,92.92,53.0],
                 [-0.272,0.2828,-0.737],
                 [12.43,-0.732,0.82],
                 [52.1,62.12,37.78],
                 [0.1,0.67,-0.22],
                 [-.09,-0.28,0.22],
                 [82.1,11.12,45.78],
                 [52.1,0.12,37.78]])

for i in range(len(a)):
   all_zero: bool = True
   
   for j in range(len(a[i])):
        num_str: str = str(a[i][j])
        first_digit: int = int(num_str[1] if num_str[0] == '-' else num_str[0])
        if first_digit == 0:
            all_zero = True
        else:
            all_zero = False
            break
   
   if all_zero:
       for j in range(len(a[i])):
           a[i][j] = 0
    

print(a)
```

This checks each array, and each element of that. If the first actual digit of the each item in the array is zero, it sets each element of the array to zero.

Answer (score 0):

you have to truncate else -0.737 rounds to 1.0

```py
a[np.all( np.where(np.trunc(a)==0,True,False),axis=1)]=0
```